# How to format parts of a label bold?

Tags: shiny

I have a button with a long label parts of which I want to format bold. How to do it?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "ab1",
               label = "The first 3 words should be bold.")
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

One solution is to put the label text in a html file and then set the label with `label = includeHTML("custom_label.html")`. Is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to understand. Is it what you want:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton(inputId = "ab1",
                 label = HTML("<b>The first 3 words</b> should be bold."))
)
```